# Java: Repeat (Understanding the code)

Tags: java

could someone please explain how the return line works? 
Thank you

```
public class JavaApplication1 {
        /**
         * Repeat string <b>str</b> <b>times</b> time.
         * @param str string to repeat
         * @param times repeat str times time
         * @return generated string
         */
        public static String repeat(String str, int times) {
            return new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(repeat("*", 5));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which part of this code is unclear for you? Do you know what is class? Do you know what is constructor or method? Did you read documentation of used constructors/methods?

Comment: @Pshemo Did you read my question?

Comment: @Pshemo I wasn't asking about class, constructors or methods.

Comment: Yes, I read your question and I still don't know which part is unclear for you. `return new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str);` is nested and chained set of instructions which are not very complex. `new char[times]` is clear, it creates new char array of `size`. All new arrays are filled with some default value which in case of char is `\0` (this can be easily fond in tutorial). `new Stirng(charArray)` uses array to create String. `replace(what, replacement)` also doesn't seem unclear, but I may be wrong, so please tell me which step precisely confuses you.

Comment: @Pshemo specifically what you just answered was unclear to me. Seems like the questions was clear. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Lets say that I would rewrite this code in simpler manner like: http://pastebin.com/mWTYUdjg. Ware you really unable to understand what all of these steps do? Or was there at least one step which didn't require explaining (like `replace` which is well documented and quite intuitive)?

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to follow if it is broken down step by step

```
// str = "*" and times = 5
public static String repeat(String str, int times) {
  //we crete a new empty array which will have values {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'}
  char[] charArray = new char[times](); 
  String newstr = new String(charArray); // newstr.equals("\0\0\0\0\0")
  newstr = newstr.replace('\0', str); //we now replace all '\0' with "*"
  return newstr; //newstr.equals("*****")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**constructor** String(char[] value)
  Allocates a new String so that it represents the sequence of characters currently contained in the character array argument.

Not sure what is char[] contains in your code and what actually you are intended to do. return method can be also be done as follows,which might make you understand.

This is similar to

```
public class JavaApplication1 {
    /**
     * Repeat string <b>str</b> <b>times</b> time.
     * @param str string to repeat
     * @param times repeat str times time
     * @return generated string
     */
    public static String repeat(String str, int times) {
        String sampleString=new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str);
        return sampleString;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(repeat("*", 5));
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see a **constructor** here. `repeat` is a **method**.

Comment: String sampleString=new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str); this is a call to cosntructor

Comment: Thank you, the answers below have explained what char[] contains

Answer (score 1):

Take if from the inside out: `new char[times]` creates a character array of size `times`, an integer value passed in on the call to `repeat`. The `replace` method then replaces each occurrence of the null value in the character array with the `str` parameter, the asterisk in your case. Since the new character array is initialized by default with the null character, `\0`, the replacement takes place for each element in the array. You should get a string of 5 asterisks when you run the program.

Comment: Thank you for the help, that's the part that confused me